How do I tell Rector to not apply any changes except those related to PHP compatibility?
As title states, I'm only interested in issues that can affect PHP compatibility, but it keeps changing array() into [] etc. Any tips?
My rector.php config so far:
return static function (RectorConfig $rectorConfig): void {
    $rectorConfig->rules([]);
    $rectorConfig->sets([LevelSetList::UP_TO_PHP_82]);
    $rectorConfig->paths([
        // my paths
    ]);
};

Looks like the only way is to walk through the rules one by one and add them in the skip list? For example
    ->withSkip([
        LongArrayToShortArrayRector::class,
        // ... more rules that don't break compatibility actually
    ])

Sadly, lots of rules are related to best practice and using latest features, rather than what breaks PHP, polluting the needed changes with the recommended changes.

I couldn't find any pre-defined rule set for what you are asking, but you could create and use your own custom set as described on page https://getrector.com/documentation/set-lists

This did it for me
->withSkip([
        Rector\Php54\Rector\Array_\LongArrayToShortArrayRector::class,
    ])      

This helped me find rules
vendor/bin/rector list-rules


Yea, but the problem is, you have to add a bunch of those skips, to include everything you don't want to modify.
